# Inspektr and its usage

Tags: java, cas

I was going through details of [CAS](http://www.jasig.org/cas) project and found that it is using something called `inspektr`. I googled for some time and tried to find more details about its usage. But I did not get any information.

Can anyone provide more details about it and its usage.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: http://code.google.com/p/inspektr/w/list ?

Comment: I found another page https://github.com/dima767/inspektr/wiki/Inspektr-Auditing but still did not understand it clearly.

Answer (score 0):

Inspektr can be found here: https://github.com/dima767/inspektr with details for usage here: https://github.com/dima767/inspektr/wiki/Inspektr-Auditing

As I understand the project, it collects information from your web flow and allows you to save said data through the use of the @Audit annotations provided. If the configuration is copied from that CAS project you linked, nearly everything's configured to log to a file. Sample data logged would be the Client's IP, remote IP, the action being performed (as configured via Spring and the @Audit annotation), as well as various other things.

If you're familiar with Spring Aspects, it should be a breeze to look through the Inspektr source code to find other uses.

Answer (score 0):

Inspektr is a framework that allows us to drive audit records from Annotations utilizing an Aspect that is provided with the framework. This works for Spring Managed Beans only!
Here the github project website:

https://github.com/dima767/inspektr/wiki/Inspektr-Auditing

A good practical reference for config: https://wiki.jasig.org/display/CASUM/Auditing+and+Statistics+Via+Inspektr

The base principal here is that Inspektr allows for logging of these audit frames into the console, database, the application server log ,we can even define our own managers to log to a different medium if required.